# Can I have different classes at the same level of a TreeView hierarchy?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a hierarchy of classes that I want to display in a WPF TreeView.

- Task

  - Person
  - Items
  - Days

The classes include string properties and collections properties. It looks like this:

- Laundry

  - John
  - Items Collection

    - Clothes
    - Washing Powder
  - Days Collection

    - Sunday
    - Thursday
- Shopping

  - Millie
  - Items

    - Money
    - List
    - Bags
    - Car
  - Days

    - Saturday

I would like to display the strings (Person) as leaves and be able to drill into the collections (Items, Days) to reach the strings inside.

I found this explanation http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e40e0a8f-7758-4b69-80f6-1c657294d019/ that works well for this layout:

- Task

  - Person

    - Items

      - Days

But I can't work out how to adjust it to represent different classes at the same hierarchical level.  All help appreciated, especially an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked it out, I think.  Let me know if there's a more sensible approach than this.

This blog post helped a lot, but unfortunately the code is riddled with typos:

[David Sackstein's - HierarchicalDataTemplate and TreeView](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2009/06/04/hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-treeview.aspx)

The key is that every class that is bound to the TreeView is derived from a baseclass.  This allows you to get the different types into the TreeView by binding it to a collection of their base class. Then in the XAML you can create a HierarchicalDataTemplate for each DataType and everything just works.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="HierarchicalDataTemplateAndTreeView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HierarchicalDataTemplateAndTreeView"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Task}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="16" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Purple" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemCollection}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="12" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="11" FontStyle="Italic" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DayCollection}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="RosyBrown" FontSize="12" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Day}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="RosyBrown" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TreeView Name="treeView"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace HierarchicalDataTemplateAndTreeView
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            treeView.ItemsSource = GetData();
        }

        public List<Composite> GetData()
        {
            List<Composite> list = new List<Composite>()
            {
                new Task
                { 
                    Name = "Laundry", Children = new List<Composite>()
                    {
                        new Person { Name = "John" },
                        new ItemCollection
                        { 
                            Name = "Items", Children = new List<Composite>()
                            {
                                new Item { Name = "Clothes" },
                                new Item { Name = "Washing Powder" }
                            }
                        },

                        new DayCollection
                        {
                            Name = "Days", Children = new List<Composite>()
                            {
                                new Day { Name = "Sunday" },
                                new Day { Name = "Thursday" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                new Task
                { 
                    Name = "Shopping", Children = new List<Composite>()
                    {
                        new Person { Name = "Millie" },
                        new ItemCollection
                        { 
                            Name = "Items", Children = new List<Composite>()
                            {
                                new Item { Name = "Money" },
                                new Item { Name = "List" },
                                new Item { Name = "Bags" }
                            }
                        },

                        new DayCollection
                        {
                            Name = "Days", Children = new List<Composite>()
                            {
                                new Day { Name = "Saturday" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HierarchicalDataTemplateAndTreeView
{
    public class Composite
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Composite> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Task: Composite
    {
    }

    public class Person : Composite
    {
    }

    public class ItemCollection : Composite
    {
    }

    public class Item : Composite
    {
    }

    public class DayCollection : Composite
    {
    }

    public class Day : Composite
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks sensible to me